# Lookbehind to get the text in R regex

Tags: regex, r, lookbehind

I have data like this:

```
Good afternoon. Hello. My bro's name is John... and he said softly 0.8% : "Don't you think I am handsome??" HAHA. jiji. koko.
```

I would like to take get the sentence before the quotations, and text inside the quotation by using Look Behind regex in R.

First: I want to look for quotation marks in a bunch of text.

Second: Look back and extract 1 sentence before the quotations. If there is no sentence, it's fine. Still extract the text in the quotations.

Below is what I would like to achieve:

```
My bro's name is John... and he said softly 0.8%: "Don't you think I am handome??"
```

I tried using this, but I would like to seek help by using Look Behind regex. Thank you.

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr('[^\\.]+[\\.\\:]"([^"]*)"', x))
```

dput :

```
"Good afternoon. Hello. My bro's name is John... and he said softly 0.8% : \"Don't you think I am handsome?? \" HAHA. jiji. koko."
```

Comment: So you want also to get rid of `\\`?

Comment: @Pascal I want to extract 1 sentence before the quotation, and the text inside the quotations.

Comment: So your expected output is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `gsub`.  We match one or more characters that is not a `.` followed by a `.` and one or more space (`\\s+`) or one or more space followed by one or more characters that are not space till the end of the string (`$`) and replace with `''`.

```
gsub('[^.]+\\.\\s+|\\s+[^ ]+$', '', str1)
#[1] "My bro's name is John... and he said softly 0.8% : \"Don't you think I am handsome?? \""
```

Or we match one or more characters that are not a `.` followed by a `.` followed by one or more space (`\\s+`), then we capture the rest of the string until the `"` followed by one or more characters (`.*`) to the end of the string and replace with the capture group (`\\1`).

```
gsub('^[^.]+\\.\\s+(.*(?:"[^"]+")).*$', '\\1', str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "My bro's name is John... and he said softly 0.8% : \"Don't you think I am handsome?? \""
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to use LookBehind?

Comment: @user5566552 Updated with a slight modification

Comment: Thank you, Could you please explain to me the code. Thanks.

Comment: I would just want to extract 1 sentence before the quotations. If I have: " Good afternnon. Hello. My bro's name is John... and he said softly: \" Don't you think I am handsome?? \"  Haha. " I do not want to get "Hello." but using this, "Hello" is captured.

Comment: The lookbehind regex, i still getting Hello

Comment: I would first want to find quotation marks in a paragraph, and from there, I would want to extract 1 sentence before the quotation marks. @akrun